# SqlAlchemy extending an existing query with additional select columns from raw sql

Tags: python, sql, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm quite new to SQLAlchemy and Python, and have to fix some bugs in a legacy environment so please bear with me..

**Environment**:

Python 2.7.18

Bottle: 0.12.7

SQLAlchemy: honestly don't know but something from 2014 (might be 0.9.8?)

MySQL: 5.7

**Scenario**: I have this SQL Statement below that pivots a linked table and adds rows dynamically as additional columns in the original table - I constructed it in SQL Workbench and it returns the results I want: All specified columns from table t1 plus the additional columns with values from table t2 appear in the result

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; --this is needed to prevent the group_concat function to cut off after 1024 characters, there are quite a few columns involved that easily exceed the original limit
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
  'SUM(
  CASE WHEN custom_fields.FIELD_NAME = "', custom_fields.FIELD_NAME, '" THEN
custom_fields_tags_link.field_value END) 
  AS "', custom_fields.FIELD_NAME, '"')
) AS t0
INTO @sql
FROM tags t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_fields_tags_link t2 ON t1.id = t2.tag_id JOIN
custom_fields ON custom_fields.id = t2.custom_field_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tags.id AS tags_id,
tags.tag_type AS tags_tag_type, tags.name AS
tags_name, tags.version AS tags_version, ', @sql,
' FROM tags LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_fields_tags_link ON tags.id = 
custom_fields_tags_link.tag_id JOIN custom_fields ON custom_fields.id = 
custom_fields_tags_link.custom_field_id GROUP BY tags.id');
SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Problem**: I have an already existing SQLAlchemy session, that expands a query to be used for pagination. Currently this query returns all my specified columns from table t1, that are joined with tables t2 and custom_fields to get all necessary columns. The missing part is the SQLAlchemy representation for the SELECT GROUP_CONCAT part of the above statement, the rest is all taken care of - since I have control and know how the Frontend presenation of this table looks and now also the raw SQL version in SQL Workbench, I tried to work backwards to get the SQLAlchemy / Python part right by consulting https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html#orm-queryguide-selecting-text and https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.columns, but now I am stuck at how to get this `TextClause` object converted into a `TextualSelect` without typing the columns statically in the `.column()` function cause I don't know what the column names, that the users provide for these custom_fields, will be.

**Goal**: concat a dynamically created raw SQL statement to my existing SQLAlchemy query to select these dynamically created fields from a linked table so that I have the same result as when I execute this raw SQL statement in a SQL editor

**Attempts**:

```
#session is a app-wide shared MySQL session object that is created via sqlalchemy.orm's sessionmaker, scoped_session function
alchemy = session.query(Tag)
try:
  #mainly the next line will be changed (x)
  select_custom_fields_columns_stmt = select().from_statement(text(
  '''SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'SUM(
      CASE WHEN custom_fields.FIELD_NAME = "', custom_fields.FIELD_NAME, '" THEN
      custom_fields_tags_link.field_value END) AS "', custom_fields.FIELD_NAME, '"')) 
    AS t0
      INTO @sql
      FROM tags t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN custom_fields_tags_link t2 ON t1.id = t2.tag_id JOIN custom_fields ON custom_fields.id = t2.custom_field_id;''')) #or here after the statement (y)
  # next line is my attempt to add the columns that have been generated by the previous function but of course unsuccessful
  alchemy = alchemy.add_columns(select_custom_fields_columns_stmt)
except:
  logException()
joined_query = alchemy.outerjoin(model.tag.CustomFieldTagLink)
.join(model.tag.CustomField)
```

*A*: This results in this error: `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'from_statement'`

*B*: Changing the line (x) above that constructs the query for the additional rows to `select_custom_fields_columns_stmt = session.select().from_statement(text(...`
--> results in: `AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'select'`

*C*: adding a `.subquery("from_custom_fields")` statement at (y) --> results in: `AttributeError: 'AnnotatedTextClause' object has no attribute 'alias'`

*D*: other attempts for (x) substituting `select()` with `session.query()` or `session.query(Tags)` also didn't result in additional columns

What else can I try? Would it be preferable/easier to write the whole raw SQL part in SQLAlchemy and if so, how could I do that?

--

**Update & Examples**:

As suggested I have provided a SQLfiddle that has all the relevant information, but doesn't return any results (I am too inexperienced on how to use it):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a0c87/2

Also provided a DB-fiddle example with the exact same information to re-create a minimal example and here also the results are returned:

https://dbfiddle.uk/NtPVWU8D

**ORM definitions**

for the 3 relevant tables, basically the Tags table and the CustomFields table use a CustomFieldTagLink association table to establish the link between these two.

```
class Tag(Base,Versioned):
__tablename__ = 'tags'
__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

#base
id                            = Column(Unicode(255), primary_key=True)
tag_type                      = Column(UnicodeText)
barcode_id                    = Column(UnicodeText)
name                          = Column(UnicodeText)
created_at                    = Column(Integer, index=True)
# version gets created automatically


# Relationship with the custom fields table - syntactic sugar 
custom_fields                 = relationship("CustomField", secondary='custom_fields_tags_link', back_populates='linked_tags')

custom_field_links            = relationship("CustomFieldTagLink", back_populates='tag', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan")

class CustomField(Base, Versioned):
__tablename__ = 'custom_fields'
__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

id                            = Column(Integer, Sequence('custom_template_field_id'), primary_key=True)
field_name                    = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
field_type                    = Column(Unicode(255), server_default='text') 
default_value                 = Column(TEXT(length=4294967295))

linked_tags                   = relationship("Tag", secondary='custom_fields_tags_link', back_populates='custom_fields')
tag_links                     = relationship("CustomFieldTagLink", back_populates='custom_field')

class CustomFieldTagLink(Base,Versioned):
'''
Association Table between Tags and Custom Fields
'''
__tablename__  = 'custom_fields_tags_link'
__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'} 

tag_id                        = Column(Unicode(255), ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)
custom_field_id               = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('custom_fields.id'), primary_key=True)
field_value                   = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)

tag                           = relationship("Tag", back_populates='custom_field_links')
custom_field                  = relationship("CustomField", back_populates='tag_links')
```

I expect the SQL query when executed to return a list of Tags items that are later processed and converted to dicts, however in this instance it is about adding the "pivot table" with the added custom_fields columns to the tags table to the already existing SQLAlchemy query object, as the execution of that statement happens later (filter, sort, paginate etc needs first to be done)

Comment: Could you please create a minimal fiddle with the tables/columns involved and some stub data on SQLfiddle or the like? Also are you going to use ORMs? If so, please post your definitions, if not, are you just expecting a list of dicts from the query?

Comment: thank you for the suggestions @soulseekah, I have added the requested info, please let me know if you need more data to reproduce it